# how to copy txt file (containing structs) to linked list c

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, malloc

I am new to c programming. In my program I have to make a database to store students. The program has to allow to enter marks, id, name and store           (as struct)in linked list and also store in file and also read from file into linked list. The only problem I have is that when I close the .exe program and then select to read from .txt file into linked list it does not work. No errors came when I compiled the code but when I AFTERWARDS select DISPLAY REPORT OF ALL STUDENTS no records are shown. This is a minor problem, please suggest how to fix this.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct phbook
{
    int number;
    char name[20];
    int mark;
    struct part *next;
};

//struct phbook *find_student(int number);
//void insertFull(struct phbook* list, int number, char Name[10],int mark);

struct phbook* insert(struct phbook *list);
struct phbook* insertFull(struct phbook* list,
                          int number,
                          char Name[10],
                          int mark);
void readFile(struct phbook* list);

int main(void)
{
    struct phbook *list = NULL;
    int code;
    int opt1;
    int courses, i, k, j, counter;
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Enter operation code: \n");
        printf("(1) ADD NEW STUDENT DETAILS: \n");
        printf("(2) SEARCH STUDENT DETAILS: \n");
        printf("(3) DISPLAY REPORT OF ALL STUDENTS: \n");
        printf("(4) SAVE ALL STUDENT RECORDS TO EXTERNAL FILE: \n");
        printf("(5) LOAD ALL STUDENT RECORDS FROM EXTERNAL FILE: \n");
        scanf(" %d", &code);
        switch (code)
        {
            case 1:
                list = insert(list);
                break;
            case 2: //search();
                break;
                break;
            case 3:
                print(list);
                break;
            case 4:
                saveToFile(list);
                break;
            case 5:
                readFile(list);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Illegal code\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/*struct phbook *find_student(int number)
 {
 struct phbook *p;
 for (p = list; p != NULL && number != p->number; p = p->next);//was sorted
 if (p != NULL && number == p->number)
 return p;
 return NULL;
 }*/

struct phbook* insert(struct phbook *list)
{

    struct phbook *cur;
    struct phbook *prev;
    struct phbook *new_node;
    new_node = (struct phbook*) malloc(sizeof(struct phbook));
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("db full er1.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("enter student id");
    scanf("%d", &new_node->number);
    for (cur = list, prev = NULL; cur != NULL && new_node->number > cur->number;
            prev = cur, cur = cur->next)
        ;
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", &new_node->name); //readline(new_node->name, NAME_LEN)
    printf("Enter MARK: ");
    scanf("%d", &new_node->mark);

    new_node->next = cur;
    if (prev == NULL)
        list = new_node;
    else
        prev->next = new_node;

    return list;
}

void search(void)
{
    int number;
    struct phbook *p;
    printf("Enter ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    p = find_student(number);
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("Name: %s\n", p->name);
        printf("Marks: %d\n", p->mark);
    }
    else
        printf("student not found.\n");
}

void print(struct phbook *list)
{
    struct phbook *p;
    printf("Student_Number Student_Name Student_Mark\n");
    for (p = list; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        printf("%7d %-25s %d\n", p->number, p->name, p->mark);
}

void saveToFile(struct phbook *list)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("results.txt", "w");

    struct phbook* cur = list; //he
    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", list->name);
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", cur->number);
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", cur->mark);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void readFile(struct phbook* list)
{
    FILE* fp;
    if (!(fp = fopen("results.txt", "r")))
        printf("File NOT Found");
    else
    {
        struct phbook *cur;
        struct phbook *prev;
        char TempName[10];
        int TempNumber;
        int TempMark;
        int done = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int success; //dummy
        cur = list; //sets it to the head (first nde of ll)
        if (list == NULL)
            ;
        printf("List is null\n");

        if (cur == NULL)
            printf("List is null\n");

        while (cur != NULL)
        {
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        while (done == 0)
        {
            success = fscanf(fp, "%s", TempName);
            if (success == 1)
            {
                success = fscanf(fp, "%d", &TempNumber);
                if (success == 1)
                {
                    success = fscanf(fp, "%d", &TempMark);

                    if (success == 1)
                    {
                        insertFull(list, TempNumber, TempName, TempMark);
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                done = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

struct phbook* insertFull(struct phbook* list,
                          int number,
                          char Name[10],
                          int mark)
{
    struct phbook *cur;
    struct phbook *prev;
    struct phbook *new_node;
    new_node = (struct phbook*) malloc(sizeof(struct phbook));
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("db full er1.\n");
        return;
    }

    for (cur = list, prev = NULL; cur != NULL && new_node->number > cur->number;
            prev = cur, cur = cur->next)
        ;
    new_node->number = number;
    new_node->mark = mark;
    strcpy(new_node->name, Name);
    new_node->next = cur;
    if (prev == NULL)
        list = new_node;
    else
        prev->next = new_node;
    return list;
}
```

the screenshot is this:

Screen shot was already MIA when I got here - user4581301

Comment: You don't want people telling you to use `std::string`, so I removed the C+++ tag when I formatted the code. No clue where your screenshot is, though.

Comment: tell us what you know. Did you open the output file with an editor to see if the input/write is working? Here's a tip; separate the input of data from the insert operation. Now you can test the insert operation with test code that doesn't need user input. you can call one or more inserts with known values. to test its operation.

Comment: Check your compiler warnings. You have a couple of nasty surprises coming if you don't. For example, `insertFull` has a return that doesn't return anything. Program will misbehave if you ever execute that case.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings.  (for `gcc` at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wexra -pedantic`  I also use `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`)  Then fix those warnings.  As it is, the posted code causes the compiler to output 26 warnings!  Please fix the code, then post an edit with the corrected code.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans:  1) use meaningful variable names.   Variable names should indicate contents or usage (or better, both).  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line

Comment: this expression, in a `for()` statement: `p != NULL;` is just cluttering the code.  suggest: `p`.  BTW:  `p` is a meaningless variable name.  Suggest something like: `pStudent` or `phonebookOfStudents`   Note: better to type some extra characters that clarify rather than cryptic names like `p`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when writing code, please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.   Piling a bunch of variable declarations into a single statement creates problems with documentation, readability, etc.

Comment: why are there two `break;` statements in case 2: in the switch statement?  Suggest replacing the first `break;` statement with a `printf()` statement indicating that functionality is not implemented.

Comment: the function: `find_student()`  is currently commented out via `/*` and `*/`.  That will not work if the function contained any `C` comments.   Suggest using a leading `#if 0`  and trailing `#endif`

Comment: in C, when calling any of the memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), do not cast the returned value.  The returned type is already a `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.   Casting just clutters the code making understanding,debugging, maintenance much more difficult.

Comment: in the definition of the `struct phbook`, this line: `struct part *next;` does not compile.  The line should be: `struct phbook *next;`

Comment: when displaying a message that is announcing an error condition, output it to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  regarding this line: `printf("File NOT Found");`,  That may or may not be the reason the call to `fopen()` failed.  suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "fopen for results.txt failed due to: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );`  which will require the statement: `#include <errno.h>`

Comment: this code does not do what is being expected: `if (list == NULL)
            ;
        printf("List is null\n");`   Suggest: `if( !list ) ) { printf( "student phone book is empty\n" );  }

Comment: these two lines: `if (cur == NULL)
            printf("List is null\n");` do nothing and can be removed

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, when using the '%s' format specifier, always use a max length modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  I.E. this line: `success = fscanf(fp, "%s", TempName);` should be: `success = fscanf(fp, "%9s", TempName);`  AND the returned value for all such calls should be checked to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the call to `insertfull()`  is not checking the returned pointer AND any returned value is not being used.  Suggest changing the return type to `void` and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute your application the main list will be null.

When you then call `readFile()`, you will not update the list in main.  You just pass the pointer by value, so that you'll update the local paramater of that function.  By the way, the call to `insertFull()` has the almost the same problem:  it returns the list following the insertion, but you ignore this return.

Change these two functions, so that they both return the list, like you do  for `insert()`:

```
struct phbook* readFile(struct phbook* list) 
{
    ...
             list = insertFull(list, TempNumber, TempName, TempMark);
    ...
    return list; 
}
```

and of course adapt your function prototype at the beginning, and updated the menu handling:

```
        case 5:
            list = readFile(list);
            break;
```

Comment: also where exactly should I enter the return list;

Comment: The return at the very end o the function, to be sure that it will always return a list.

Comment: how do I return the list for insertFull?

Comment: @Saavin yes: you already manage the insertFull() by returning a list.  It's therefore sufficient to change readFile() as demonstrated above.  if you don't do `list = ...`  the pointer to the new list will be lost (i.e. the update of list in insertFull will remain local to that function) (yes, local variables/parameters can have the same name in different functions, yet they are independen variables).

Comment: thank you very much sir, your advise worked. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

the following code compiles cleanly

However, it will not link because the function: `find_student()` is commented out.

Examination of the code indicates it will not fully perform all the desired functionality.  So you will still have to debug the execution.

Suggest using a debugger, like `gdb`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LEN (20)

struct phbook
{
    int studentID;
    char studentName[ MAX_NAME_LEN ];
    int studentGrade;
    struct phbook *next;
};

// prototypes
struct phbook* insert(struct phbook* );
struct phbook* find_student( int );
void insertFull( struct phbook*, int, char *, int );
void readFile  ( struct phbook* );
void print     ( struct phbook* );
void saveToFile( struct phbook* );


int main(void)
{
    struct phbook *list = NULL;
    int code;

    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Enter operation code: \n");
        printf("(1) ADD NEW STUDENT DETAILS: \n");
        printf("(2) SEARCH STUDENT DETAILS: \n");
        printf("(3) DISPLAY REPORT OF ALL STUDENTS: \n");
        printf("(4) SAVE ALL STUDENT RECORDS TO EXTERNAL FILE: \n");
        printf("(5) LOAD ALL STUDENT RECORDS FROM EXTERNAL FILE: \n");
        scanf(" %d", &code);

        switch (code)
        {
            case 1:
                list = insert(list);
                break;

            case 2: //search();
                break;
                break;

            case 3:
                print(list);
                break;

            case 4:
                saveToFile(list);
                break;

            case 5:
                readFile(list);
                break;

            default:
                printf("Illegal code\n");
        } // end switch

        printf("\n");
    } // end for()
} // end function: main


#if 0
struct phbook *find_student(int studentID)
{
    struct phbook *p;
    for (p = list; p != NULL && studentID != p->studentID; p = p->next);//was sorted

    return p;
} // end function: find_student
#endif


struct phbook* insert(struct phbook *list)
{
    struct phbook *cur;
    struct phbook *prev;
    struct phbook *new_node;

    if( NULL == (new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct phbook)) ) )
    {
        perror( "malloc for struct phbook failed");
        return NULL;
    }

    // implied else malloc successful

    printf("enter student id");
    scanf("%d", &new_node->studentID);

    for (cur = list, prev = NULL;
        cur != NULL && new_node->studentID > cur->studentID;
        prev = cur, cur = cur->next)
    {
        ;
    }

    printf("Enter studentName: ");
    scanf("%19s", new_node->studentName); //readline(new_node->studentName, NAME_LEN)

    printf("Enter MARK: ");
    scanf("%d", &new_node->studentGrade);

    new_node->next = cur;

    if (!prev)
    {
        list = new_node;
    }

    else
    {
        prev->next = new_node;
    }

    return list;
} // end function: search


void search(void)
{
    int studentID;
    struct phbook *p;
    printf("Enter ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &studentID);

    if( NULL == (p = find_student(studentID) ) )
    {
        printf("studentName: %s\n", p->studentName);
        printf("Marks: %d\n", p->studentGrade);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("student not found.\n");
    }
} // end function: search


void print(struct phbook *list)
{
    struct phbook *p;
    printf("Student_Number Student_studentName Student_Mark\n");
    for (p = list; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        printf("%7d %-25s %d\n", p->studentID, p->studentName, p->studentGrade);
} // end function: print


void saveToFile(struct phbook *list)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("results.txt", "w");

    struct phbook* cur = list; //he
    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", list->studentName);
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", cur->studentID);
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", cur->studentGrade);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    fclose(fp);
} // end function: saveToFile


void readFile( struct phbook* list)
{
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    if (!(fp = fopen("results.txt", "r")))
    {
        perror( "fopen for read of results.txt failed");
        return;
    }

    //implied else, fopen successful

    char TempstudentName[10];
    int TempNumber;
    int TempMark;

    while (3 == fscanf(fp, " %19s %d %d", TempstudentName, &TempNumber, &TempMark ) )
    {
        insertFull(list, TempNumber, TempstudentName, TempMark);
    }
} // end function; readFile


void insertFull(struct phbook* list,
                          int  studentID,
                          char studentName[10],
                          int  studentGrade)
{
    struct phbook *cur;
    struct phbook *prev;
    struct phbook *new_node;

    if( NULL == (new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct phbook)) ) )
    {
        perror( "malloc for size of struct phbook failed" );
        return;
    }

    for (cur = list, prev = NULL;
        cur != NULL && new_node->studentID > cur->studentID;
        prev = cur, cur = cur->next)
    {
        ;
    }

    new_node->studentID = studentID;
    new_node->studentGrade = studentGrade;
    strcpy(new_node->studentName, studentName);
    new_node->next = cur;

    if (!prev)
    {
        list = new_node;
    }

    else
    {
        prev->next = new_node;
    }
} // end function: insertFull
```

I did not add all the necessary error checking, so you will have to do that.

I added the missing prototypes

I corrected several minor coding errors